# Angular Bind once syntax with default value also bind once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Ran in to a quirky bind once syntax issue.  Wondering if you may have run into this?

```
{{::obj.attr1 || obj.attr2}}
```

The above works.  However, what I really want to do is ensure that even the defaulted value has bind once semantics as well, like:

```
{{::obj.attr1 || ::obj.attr2}}
```

However, this syntax is not acceptable.  I also tried `::{{obj.attr1 || obj.attr2}}` without luck.

Any ideas how to make this syntax acceptable?

Thanks!

Comment: `{{::obj.attr1 || obj.attr2}}` this is one time binding for both attr1 and attr2. Just use first snippet.

Comment: Thanks!  I wish the syntax more clearly depicted the intent, but I guess I can learn to read it that was as well.

Comment: Think about it as an one-time binding for entire expression: `{{:: (obj.attr1 || obj.attr2) }}`. So it just means that this expression inside `()` will be evaluated only once and after that watcher will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your first snippet is correct:

```
{{::obj.attr1 || obj.attr2}}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p34cygks/) comparing this with normal `{{obj || obj2}}` syntax